# ANTLR4: How to find the root rules in a gramar which maybe used to find the start rule

Tags: antlr4, antlrworks2

I have been looking at the grammars located at:

[Antlr 4 grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)

and I have been using Antlrworks 2 to view them, however I am finding it difficult to locate the start rule for the entire grammar.

I think the definition of a start rule is a node which has no other pointers to it, does anyone have a working solution to find the start rule for these grammars?

Comment: Technically, you can use any parser rule as a start rule. It only depends on which part of the grammar you want to parse (in the code, which method you invoke). But usually you look for the more abstract composition in the domain of the grammar, usually something like `program`, `document` or `query`. There is no hard rule.

Comment: yes :( I wanted a method without manually looking. I want the root node for the AST. It doesnt take long but it would be handy to be able to detect the root node.

Comment: The root node depends on the rule you used to start parsing. It's only a matter of definition what you consider the start rule. As a rule of thumb: usually (but not always) the rule that is meant to be the most used entrance is at the top of a grammar file.

Comment: I can see the confusion, the specific start rule which I am after is the rule which can be used to parse all the constructs in the file. So if you took the grammar, it could be used to recognize any file of that language as opposed to a subset of files. I don't know the terminology but what im after is the highest root possible in the grammar file. Another confusion is that I am not trying to find a start rule im trying to find a specific start rule which defines the start of the whole language. The start terminology I used here is conflicting with "start rule"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the root/start rule I have implemented a ANTLR tree listener which creates an adjacency list of all the rules in an ANTLR grammar and check to see if no other grammar rule references it. This would give a hint as to what the start rule might be.

To run this you will need the antlr grammar taken from [Antlr 4 grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr4)

Here is the listener implementation:

(RootFinder.java)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;


public class RootFinder extends ANTLRv4ParserBaseListener {

    private Set<String> rules = new HashSet<String>( );
    public Map<String, Set<String>> adjacencyList = new LinkedHashMap<String, Set<String>>( );

    public void enterParserRuleSpec(ANTLRv4Parser.ParserRuleSpecContext ctx)
    {
        rules = new HashSet<String>( );     
    }

    public void exitParserRuleSpec(ANTLRv4Parser.ParserRuleSpecContext ctx)
    {
        if(ctx != null)
        {
            adjacencyList.put(ctx.RULE_REF().getText(), rules);
        }
    }

    public void exitRuleref(ANTLRv4Parser.RulerefContext ctx) {
        if(ctx != null)
        {
            rules.add(ctx.getText());
        }
    }

    public List<String> leafNodes( )
    {
        List<String> leafs = new ArrayList<String>( );
        for(Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : adjacencyList.entrySet())
        {
            if( entry.getValue().size() == 0)
            {
                leafs.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return leafs;
    }

    public Set<String> rootNodes( )
    {
        Set<String> roots = new HashSet<String>( );
        Collection<Set<String>> values = adjacencyList.values();

        for(Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : adjacencyList.entrySet())
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for(Set<String> vals : values)
            {
                if(vals.contains(entry.getKey()))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if(found == false)
            {
                roots.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return roots;
    }
}
```

and here is the Main program that runs it

(Main.java)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRFileStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String filename = args[0];
        ANTLRInputStream reader = new ANTLRFileStream(filename);
        ANTLRv4Lexer lexer = new ANTLRv4Lexer(reader);
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ANTLRv4Parser parser = new ANTLRv4Parser(tokenStream);
        RootFinder rootfinder = new RootFinder();
        parser.addParseListener(rootfinder);

        ParseTree tree = parser.grammarSpec();
        System.out.println(rootfinder.leafNodes());
        System.out.println(rootfinder.rootNodes());
    }

}
```